# Google VR SDK unity package not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am encountering a strange problem and I am clueless about what to do. I start a new Unity (32 bit) project  Then I import Google VR SDK and encounter 3 errors.

*Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/Emulator/EmulatorClientSocket.cs(66,64): error CS1729: The type `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' does not contain a constructor that takes`2' arguments

Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/Emulator/EmulatorClientSocket.cs(70,17): error CS0200: Property or indexer `System.Diagnostics.Process.StartInfo' cannot be assigned to (it is read only)

Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Controller/Internal/Emulator/EmulatorClientSocket.cs(79,17): error CS1061: Type `System.Diagnostics.Process' does not contain a definition for`Close' and no extension method `Close' of type`System.Diagnostics.Process' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I dont even touch anything just import unity package coming with Google VR SDK.
Does anyone has any idea about this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This is due to the fact that in some version of Unity, the default platform is WebGL.
You can solve this by switching to the Android platform in File | Build Settings.](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/228)

You can switch the platform by File -> Build Setting -> select Android and click Switch Platform